# RESTful APIs - create but don't lookup

Tags: database, web-services, rest

In the context of RESTful APIs, what is an example of a real world object, that would make sense to Create but not Lookup? Is there one?

--Edit--
The question was to ask if there exists a usecase where a Create API would make sense, but not necessarily a Lookup API for the object - in places where you wouldn't want to expose the data(using the lookup API) to the outside world.

Comment: Why would you store anything without wanting to retrieve it?

Comment: In a use case I've had to use in the past: you may want to publish some sort of 'Event' to all 'Listeners' in a service (say, 'user logged out', etc.).  Actually retrieving that Event in the future isn't particularly important (except for auditing's sake), it should just trigger activity within the system.

Comment: Yes, these cases exist... So ... what is the question?

Comment: What are some examples of this usecase?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about a keystroke logger...sending POSTs to create the audit trail.

You would not want to allow anyone to GET the results (besides you).